# Как в Python рассчитать конечные разности?

Tags: python, математика, numpy

Делаю полином. В рамках алгоритма считаю конечные разности. В рамках алгоритма мы идем по колонкам слева направо (см. рисунок), вычитаем из верхней строки нижестоящую и записываем результат в следующий столбец справа в ячейку сверху.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Пример: в колонке `y` таблицы из 0,3091 вычитаем 0,0000 и получаем 0,3091, итог записываем в колонку `дельта y`. Затем спускаемся ниже и считаем: 0,5878 - 0,3091 = 0,2787 и проч. Надо просчитать конечные разности по всем колонкам.

Казалось бы, предложенный далее метод должен считать все корректно. Однако у меня конечные разности расходятся с расчетом преподавателя. Буду благодарен за анализ кода и замечания по нему.

Код:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return np.sin(x)

order = 4
x_i_list = [(0.1*np.pi*i) for i in range(0, 11)]

# 4.1. формируем список y_i
y_i_list = []
for x in x_i_list:
    y_i = (func(x)) 
    y_i_list.append(y_i)

# 5. строим конечные разности
if order < len(y_i_list):
    result_1 = [ np.diff(y_i_list, n=d) for d in np.arange(1, len(y_i_list)) ] 
    print('Конечные разности по столбцам: ', result_1)
else:
    print(f'Определите порядок полинома меньше {len(y_i_list)-1}')
```

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, я смотрю свой код: в, вроде бы, все верно. Но есть предположение, что это не так. Потому что дальнейший расчет дает более-менее не нулевую погрешность. Да, там могут быть траблы и дальше по скрипту, но препод дает другие разности, что может свидетельствовать об ошибке у меня

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, это как раз таки мой расчет, не методичка. Но почему кривая по `x`  и `y`? Здесь `x` задает сетку через генератор списка, `y` считается подставлением иксов в функцию

Comment: Последнее значение *x*: *pi = 3.141592653589793*. Округленно должно быть *3.142*. У вас *3.140*.

Comment: Второе значение *y*. Если `np.sin(np.pi / 10)`, то *0.3090*.  Если `np.sin(0.314)`, то *0.3089*. У вас *0.3091*.

Comment: Если столбец *y* вычислен точно, он должен быть симметричным. У вас нет.

Comment: Таблица не соответствует коду. Я бы рекомендовал закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Зачем вы используете списки, если все можно сделать numpy массивами, np.arange или np.linspace?
y=np.sin(x) это проще и понятнее, чем у вас. У np.diff есть параметр n , используйте его.

Comment: @AlexAlex, ТС использовал параметр  `n`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, возможно, таблица ввела в заблуждение. Привел ее, чтобы показать в качестве примера расчета конечных разностей. Да, там значения могут не совпадать: изначально считал с округлением. Yареканий в сторону `np.diff()` не прозвучало: возможно, все-таки алгоритм здесь считает верно: я пробовал без `np.diff()` решать - там более громоздко и не факт, что более правильно